# tbb "task" local storage

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

Assume I have the following code

```
tbb::enumerable_thread_specific<std::set<int>> tls;
tbb::parallel_for(0, n, [&] (int i) {
  auto &traversedVisited = tls.local();
  // do a bfs using traversedVisited
});
```

Assume **no** other parallel_for are happening in the bfs parts (avoiding the problem mentioned in the task_isolation documentation). I know tls variable will provide thread-local storage, so there are no contentions between parallel_for tasks that are spawn on the same thread.  However, if I understand correctly, those tasks (that are spawned on the same thread) share the same thread-local storage. Suppose tasks A and B are spawned on thread 1. Is it possible A is executed halfway and paused and B is turned in and starts to execute? If that is possible, then "traversedVisited" may not be valid for both A and B. Or are tbb tasks always atomic? If not, what's the solution for the situation mentioned at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Both tasks A & B are independent of each other based on their dependencies. They will **execute parallelly** in the same task arena with individual local storage(TLS). And by default, TBB tasks are not atomic, we need to explicitly make them atomic based on the use-case.

For more information refer to the concept "The TBB Thread Pool (the Market) and Task Arenas" from the below link:
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4842-4398-5.pdf

Comment: Yes, A and B are independent. Let's say we have 100 such tasks but we only have 2 threads for that arena. At a time, at most 2 tasks will be executed at the same time. Suppose 50 tasks will be executed on thread 1 and the other 50 tasks will be on thread 2. I'm wondering if a task on thread 1 could be suspended halfway and then thread 1 goes for another task. Or, will tbb guarantee that if a task is distributed to thread 1, thread 1 will finish that task before performing another task? Certainly, assume within each task there is no "parallel_for" happening.

Comment: No task will be suspended halfway. We need to do suspend and resume the tasks explicitly if needed. For more information you can refer to the below link:
https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/1.0-rev-3/elements/oneTBB/source/task_scheduler/scheduling_controls/resumable_tasks.html